# How to generate Angular cli sitemap.xml and robots.txt

Tags: angular, sitemap.xml

Is there is any plugin/library that is generate an angular sitemap
how to do that?

I tried `Sitemap Generator` but it did not worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 sitemap and robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352653/angular-8-sitemap-and-robots-txt)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.